# restore data partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, data-recovery

I have a Windows 10 laptop. I installed ubuntu on it and messed up the windows boot loader months ago, but ubuntu 19.04 (recently upgraded) works. I've recently started trying to fix the bootloader, and I was following the instructions [here](https://dunia-it.com/heres-how-to-fix-windows-10-bootloader-from-linux/).

I ran these commands

```
sudo apt-get install syslinux
sudo dd if=/usr/lib/syslinux/mbr/mbr.bin of=/dev/sda3
sudo apt-get install mbr
sudo install-mbr -i n -p D -t 0 /dev/sda3
```

sda3 is my windows data partition. I think I misunderstood what the instructions said about "Don’t forget to replace “sda” with the Windows 10 system drive." but idk.

Now I cannot access the files on /dev/sda3 and I'm worried that even if I do fix my windows bootloader that now it won't be able to load the data!

How can I get access back to /dev/sda3 and view the files on it?

I tried:

```
mount /dev/sda3
mount: /dev/sda3: can't find in /etc/fstab.
```

And here is what it looks like in gparted:
[image]

Comment: Usually that error is from Windows fast start up, which sets the hibernation flag. Ubuntu's NTFSfix only does minor fixes & you need to run Windows chkdsk from your Windows repair flash drive if that is the issue. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions And your show an efi partition, so would not use a BIOS boot loader like syslinux. You would need UEFI boot repairs. Many times with UEFI you can directly boot Windows from UEFI, if grub will not boot it.

Comment: I can access my data again now, so that part is solved, but I can't get windows to boot. What do you mean by "directly boot Windows from UEFI"? A link might help! I've used boot-repair and grub doesn't even show the windows option any more. It used to, but gave errors. I guess I probably need to post a new question about my whole boot situation.

Comment: UEFI has a boot menu, the same key you used to boot Ubuntu live installer, often f10 or f12 but varies by vendor. Grub only boots working Windows, or Windows that is not hibernated. And fast start uses hibernation flag, so that must be off. Windows also may turn fast start back on with updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. I think it was:

```
sudo apt-get install ntfsfix
ntfsfix /dev/sda3
```

I think that's the one that did it.
Credit to https://linuxacademy.com/blog/linux/ntfs-partition-repair-and-recovery-in-linux/

https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/fsck-command-examples was of some help too, but `fsck` didn't get me there.

Comment: Later, I broke things even worse and corrupted my entire partition table. So I downloaded [testdisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) and I was able to fix all my partitions with that by re-creating the partition table based upon a boot-repair log previously made. Not sure if testdisk might have worked for this problem too.

Answer (score 0):

I made a similar mistake & deleted my primary Ubuntu partition, the file-system, not the data within. 
So the partition ended up as unallocated. I was able to reboot into it but not happy seeing that unallocated label on /dev/sda2. (Partition 1 is Windows) 
After making a backup & knowing I had Ubuntu on usb drive, I decided to experiment prior to re-installing the system.
So using the utility 'Disks' this allowed me to highlight the unallocated partition and then click on gear icon,  then 'Format Partition...'
Clicking on will bring up dialog Erase. Choose "Don't overwrite existing data (Quick)"
For the Type option I chose 'Compatible with Linux systems (Ext4)'
Click on 'Format...', and now the partition comes up as Ext4.

Using GParted, I find there is a now a small 1 MiB unallocated partition but probably not worth fussing with.
Worth trying first, may save you a re-install.